# Python Regex to Java

Tags: java, python, regex

I am trying to convert a python regex to java. It finds a match in python but fails on the same string in java.

Python regex : `"(CommandLineEventConsumer)(\x00\x00)(.*?)(\x00)(.*?)({})(\x00\x00)?([^\x00]*)?".format(event_consumer_name)`

Java regex : `"(CommandLineEventConsumer)(\\u0000\\u0000)(.*?)(\\u0000)(.*?)(" + event_consumer_name + ")(\\u0000\\u0000)?([^\\u0000]*)?"`

I also tried this : `"(CommandLineEventConsumer)(\\x00\\x00)(.*?)(\\x00)(.*?)(" + event_consumer_name + ")(\\x00\\x00)?([^\\x00]*)?"`

What I'm I missing please?

I have attached a piece of the code

```
String sampleStr = "\u0000\u0000�\u0003\b\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u000B\u0000\u0000\u0000���\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0000WMIDataID\u0000\u0000SystemVersion\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\f\u0000.\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000)\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0000\u0000�\u0003\b\u0000\u0000\u0000'\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u000B\u0000\u0000\u0000��/\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000B\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000string\u0000\u0000WMIDataID\u0000\f\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0016\u0000\u0000\u0000R\u0000O\u0000O\u0000T\u0000\\\u0000M\u0000i\u0000c\u0000r\u0000o\u0000s\u0000o\u0000f\u0000t\u0000\\\u0000H\u0000o\u0000m\u0000e\u0000N\u0000e\u0000t\u0000\u0019\u0000\u0000\u0000H\u0000N\u0000e\u0000t\u0000_\u0000C\u0000o\u0000n\u0000n\u0000e\u0000c\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000P\u0000r\u0000o\u0000p\u0000e\u0000r\u0000t\u0000i\u0000e\u0000s\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000C\u0000o\u0000n\u0000n\u0000e\u0000c\u0000t\u0000i\u0000o\u0000n\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000N\u0000S\u0000_\u00005\u00001\u00001\u00006\u00002\u00006\u0000F\u0000A\u0000E\u00004\u0000F\u00005\u00007\u0000D\u0000B\u0000D\u00002\u00000\u0000D\u0000F\u00005\u0000C\u0000D\u00004\u00004\u0000A\u00004\u00001\u0000D\u0000A\u0000E\u0000C\u0000E\u0000D\u00002\u00008\u0000C\u0000F\u00007\u0000B\u00003\u0000F\u0000D\u00008\u0000B\u00001\u00002\u00000\u00001\u00002\u0000C\u00007\u0000F\u00004\u0000B\u00005\u00008\u0000F\u00004\u00004\u0000E\u00006\u00006\u00005\u0000\\\u0000K\u0000I\u0000_\u0000A\u00000\u00001\u00000\u00008\u0000C\u0000E\u00002\u00006\u00001\u0000D\u00006\u0000C\u0000D\u00007\u00000\u0000D\u00003\u00005\u00000\u0000F\u00005\u0000B\u00007\u00002\u0000F\u00002\u0000E\u00009\u00008\u00007\u00004\u0000A\u0000E\u00006\u0000E\u00000\u00000\u00004\u0000D\u00003\u00000\u00002\u00009\u00000\u00001\u00005\u0000B\u00000\u00009\u00001\u00009\u0000B\u00001\u0000B\u0000D\u00003\u00002\u00006\u0000B\u0000B\u00006\u00004\u00009\u0000\\\u0000I\u0000_\u0000E\u0000D\u0000C\u0000E\u0000A\u00001\u00004\u0000E\u0000C\u00006\u00003\u0000A\u00005\u00007\u00004\u00001\u0000F\u0000A\u0000A\u00006\u00003\u00000\u00001\u0000C\u00007\u00007\u0000C\u0000A\u00002\u00006\u00000\u0000A\u0000B\u0000E\u0000C\u00000\u0000E\u00007\u00007\u00000\u00009\u00005\u00001\u00004\u0000F\u00006\u0000A\u00003\u00002\u0000C\u00000\u00003\u00004\u00007\u0000E\u00000\u00002\u00006\u00008\u00001\u00007\u0000C\u00008\u00008\u0000\u0000\u0000WQL:Re4\u00007\u0000C\u00007\u00009\u0000E\u00006\u00002\u0000C\u00002\u00002\u00002\u00007\u0000E\u0000D\u0000D\u00000\u0000F\u0000F\u00002\u00009\u0000B\u0000F\u00004\u00004\u0000D\u00008\u00007\u0000F\u00002\u0000F\u0000A\u0000F\u00009\u0000F\u0000E\u0000D\u0000F\u00006\u00000\u0000A\u00001\u00008\u0000D\u00009\u0000F\u00008\u00002\u00005\u00009\u00007\u00006\u00000\u00002\u0000B\u0000D\u00009\u00005\u0000E\u00002\u00000\u0000B\u0000D\u00003\u0000�3u�&��\u0001����+\u0004�\u0001�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\f;\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000F\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000F\u0000\u0000\u0000/\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001�\u0000\u0000�\u0000__EventFilter\u0000\u001C\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0015\u0000\u0000\u0000�tw�}\n" +
            "z�p�)��\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000root\\cimv2\u0000\u0000BVTFilter\u0000\u0000SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_Processor\" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99\u0000\u0000WQL\u0000B\u0000B\u0000F\u0000C\u0000C\u0000B\u00004\u00004\u00004\u0000C\u0000F\u00006\u00006\u0000A\u0000A\u00000\u00009\u0000A\u0000E\u00006\u0000F\u00001\u00005\u00009\u00006\u00007\u0000A\u00006\u00008\u00006\u00005\u00001\u00007\u00005\u0000B\u0000B\u00000\u0000E\u0000D\u00002\u00001\u00006\u0000D\u00001\u00009\u00009\u00007\u00000\u0000A\u00007\u00009\u00008\u00008\u0000B\u00007\u00002\u0000C\u0000D\u0000F\u00000\u0000A\u00003\u0000A\u00004\u0000�3u�&��\u0001Ԏ��+\u0004�\u0001�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000F�����\"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000/\u0000\u0000\u0000O\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001A\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\\\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001q\u0000\u0000�\u0000CommandLineEventConsumer\u0000\u0000cscript KernCap.vbs\u0000\u001C\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0015\u0000\u0000\u0000�tw�}\n" +
            "z�p�)��\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000BVTConsumer\u0000\u0000C:\\\\tools\\\\kernrate\u00000\u0000A\u00007\u0000A\u0000B\u0000E\u00006\u00003\u0000F\u00003\u00006\u0000E\u00002\u0000B\u00002\u00009\u00002\u00000\u0000F\u0000E\u0000D\u0000A\u0000F\u0000A\u0000E\u00008\u00004\u00009\u00008\u00002\u00003\u0000A\u0000F\u00009\u00004\u00002\u00009\u0000C\u0000C\u00000\u0000E\u0000A\u00003\u00007\u00003\u0000F\u0000F\u0000E\u0000E\u00001\u00005\u00000\u00007\u0000E\u0000D\u0000B\u00002\u00001\u0000F\u0000D\u00009\u00001\u00007\u00000\u0000�3u�&��\u0001����+\u0004�\u0001�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�";
    String event_consumer_name = "BVTConsumer";
    String cPattern = "(CommandLineEventConsumer)(\\u0000\\u0000)(.*?)(\\u0000)(.*?)(" + event_consumer_name + ")(\\u0000\\u0000)?([^\\u0000]*)?";

    Pattern consumer_mo = Pattern.compile(cPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher consumer_match = consumer_mo.matcher(sampleStr);

    if(consumer_match.find()){
        System.out.println(consumer_match.group(6));
    }
```

UPDATE

In python the groups return

[python result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RULDX.png)

Comment: Could it be that `event_consumer_name` contains characters that you need to escape?

Comment: Please also add a test string

Comment: Its best to post a simple demo program that we can run with a quick copy/paste. A canned string and a regex should be just a few lines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: @cornuz `event_consumer_name` consumer won't need escaping. Sorry I'm new. I have added a sample code. Hope it clarifies the issue

Comment: The `(CommandLineEventConsumer)(\u0000\u0000)(.*?)(\u0000)(.*?)` part matches fine. group(3) gets `cscript KernCap.vbs` group(4) gets a null character but group(5) gets nothing. That's probably why BVTConsumer never matches.

Comment: I did try in Python and I have the exact same lack of match when I include the (BVTConsumer).

Comment: Gotcha. You have a \n in your string so the matching stops there. If you do `Pattern consumer_mo = Pattern.compile(cPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);` it does match in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I posted as comments:
The `(CommandLineEventConsumer)(\u0000\u0000)(.*?)(\u0000)(.*?)` part matches fine.
group(3) gets `cscript KernCap.vbs`
group(4) gets a null character
but group(5) gets nothing.

I did try in Python and I have the exact same lack of match when I include the (BVTConsumer). So you probably had a difference in the code doing the matching in Python, not the regex itself.

So the reason is that you have a `\n` in your string so the matching stops there. If you do

```
Pattern consumer_mo = Pattern.compile(cPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

it does match in your example.